# getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed" in MVC starter framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm noob in MVC, now I'm creating the Auth for the first time
when I open the register route :

### Fatal error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to **app\controllers\AuthController::register()** must be an instance of **app\controllers\Requset**, instance of **app\core\Request** given in `C:\controllers\AuthController.php:19` Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: **app\controllers\AuthController**->register(Object(**app\core\Request**)) #1 `C:\MVC\core\Router.php(57)`: call_user_func(Array, Object(**app\core\Request**)) #2 `C:\MVC\core\Application.php(30)`: **app\core\Router**->resolve() #3 `C:\MVC\public\index.php(23)`: **app\core\Application**->run() #4 {main} thrown in `C:\MVC\controllers\AuthController.php` on line 19

my AuthController class

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\core\Controller;
use app\core\Application; 
use app\core\Requset; 


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return $this->render('login');
    }
    public function register(Requset $request)
    {
        if($request->isPost()){
            return 'Handle submitted data';
        }
        return $this->render('register');
    }
}
```

if there's anything I messed please tell me to include it in the question

#### **EDIT**

after editing `requset` to `request` :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function app\core\Controller::render(), 1 passed in C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\controllers\AuthController.php on line 26 and exactly 2 expected in C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\core\Controller.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\controllers\AuthController.php(26): app\core\Controller->render('register') #1 [internal function]: app\controllers\AuthController->register(Object(app\core\Request)) #2 C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\core\Router.php(57): call_user_func(Array, Object(app\core\Request)) #3 C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\core\Application.php(30): app\core\Router->resolve() #4 C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\public\index.php(23): app\core\Application->run() #5 {main} thrown in C:\Users\xxgam\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\MVC\core\Controller.php on line 14

#### Another Edit

render method :

```
public function render($view, $params)
{
    return Application::$app->router->renderView($view, $params);
}
```

Comment: Requset or Request?

Comment: you're right, but I changed it and the error just changed look to the update

Comment: "function app\core\Controller::render(), 1 passed in" ... Seems like the render() function expecting 2 parameters and you're providing only one. can you share the definition of the render() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `return $this->render('register');` there's one parameter, and the method expects two, view's name and `$params`, so in the register, I don't have any `$params`, so that mean the `$params` is optional
for this, I changed `$params` to `$params = []` so if I don't write any `$params` it will automatically be an empty array

in the code :

```
public function render($view, $params)
{
    return Application::$app->router->renderView($view, $params);
}
```

to

```
public function render($view, $params = [])
{
    return Application::$app->router->renderView($view, $params);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!